# Skyrim: Special Edition (vanilla) crashes on the loading screen when starting a new game

Tags: technical-issues, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, when I start a new game via the main menu, the game will crash to the desktop.

Extra info:

- Models on main menu (dragon) and loading screen are both missing.
- The game crashes even when not using any mods.
- There is a dollar sign in front of some text.
- The game doesn't run in fullscreen mode, even when set to do so in the launcher.

Things that I already tried:

- Verifying the game's integrity via Steam.
- Removing the game and all folders and files that had something to do with the game (i.e. My Games/Skyrim: Special Edition) and then reinstalling the game.

Any information and/or help is greatly appreciated, even if it's just a suggestion that may provide some more info.

Edit:

I have since posting this question also tried the following things:

- Updating video drivers.
- Moving the install folder to another drive or just plain installing it there.

Comment: Does your computer meet the minimum specs required? This seems like very odd behavior.

Comment: It most definitely does, I'm rocking a GTX 1650, a pretty modern i5, 16GB of RAM and Windows 10 so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you have another drive that you could install the game on? It sounds like there's old files SOMEWHERE on your machine that are messing with things.

Comment: I do have another drive and I'll try removing the game and reinstalling it on that one as soon as I can get back to it. I'll update you as soon as possible.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it changed nothing. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I am quickly running out of ideas... Do you have any workshop mods that are attempting to sync/may be corrupted? Sometimes the steam workshop sneaks mods in as part of the full game install if you're still subscribed to them

Comment: No, I don't have any installed, my game is 100% vanilla. Are there perhaps any known problems with specific NVIDIA cards because I'm getting the idea that it's system-related.

Comment: Drivers up to date?

Comment: Yup, I have in the meantime updated the list of things I have tried. I know, it's really weird.

Comment: "Removing the game and all folders and files that had something to do with the game (i.e. My Games/Skyrim: Special Edition) and then reinstalling the game." Did you also remove all mod related software, SKSE, &c.? Was that a complete vanilla installation? That dollar-sign problem has to do with missing language files, I believe.

Comment: @Joachim Yup, I deleted Vortex as well so that shouldn't be a problem except if there are some mod files that were hiding somewhere. I deleted Vortex, the game, Vortex' mod staging folder and the folder in Documents/My Games. Are there any I could've missed? It is interesting to know that the dollar sign has to do with language files.

Comment: Can you try changing video settings in the .ini files, like lowering the resolution, turning of AA; and/or using NVidia Settings panel to change those settings? And I'm reading in places that changing the compatibility mode for SkyrimSE.exe might help.

Comment: It is actually possible to install SKSE *through Steam*, although this is not the usual way of doing it. But even if you did that, I cannot see how SKSE by itself could possibly cause this much chaos.